# Leaflet map marker dragging is not working properly on mobiles when disabling scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, geolocation, openstreetmap

I added an OpenStreetMap map on my project using Leaflet. I wanted to disable scrolling on mobiles and wheel scroll on desktops. I used the following options found [here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/5425#issuecomment-342055520)    and managed to achieve this.

```
const mymap = L.map('theMap', {
    dragging: !L.Browser.mobile, //disables dragging on mobiles
    tap: !L.Browser.mobile,      // mobile functionality??
    scrollWheelZoom: false       //disables wheel scrolls on desktops
}).setView([lat, lon], 13);
```

Also, a marker is displayed:

```
let marker = new  L.marker([lat,lon],{ 
draggable: true, 
dragging:true, 
autoPan: true , 
autoPanPadding: [100,100] }).addTo(mymap);
```

Everything works as expected on desktops, but the issue is with the marker on mobiles. It can't be dragged more than a couple of pixels and freely. Any options that I'm missing? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
The problem seems to be related with Leaflet 1.7 . Use the previous version.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you might have some unnecessary properties set.  All you need is the following

```
const mymap = L.map('theMap', { scrollWheelZoom: false }).setView([lat, lon], 13);

let marker = new L.marker([lat,lon], { draggable: true });
```

I have a codepen for you that demonstrates it working properly https://codepen.io/the-gis-guy/pen/LYxwpKW

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The extra properties are for disabling the scrolling on mobiles so that users can scroll the page and not the map. What you are showing works fine in my case too, but not when disabling the scrolling. I can zoom with two fingers but but the marker moves hardly some pixels from where it is.

Comment: I updated the codepen and added back the
`dragging: !L.Browser.mobile`
and it disables scroll on my mobile and lets me drag the marker.

Comment: Finally I figured out a solution! After testing your code locally I concluded that the Leaflet 1.7 version is the problem so I used the previous one (1.6). Thank you for your time!